# Let $(X ,\mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and suppose that $A$ is a subset of $X$. Then $Cl(A) = A\cup Bd(A)$. False!

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X ,\mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and suppose that $A$ is a subset of $X$. Then $Cl(A) = A\cup Bd(A)$.

I think this statement is false because the definition of closure does have the union of A and the limit points of A. However, I know that it is possible to have boundary points that are not limit points.

If I am correct what is a basic example that models this?

Comment: What is your definition of $\text{Bd}(A)$?

Comment: Let $(X,\mathfrak T)$  be a topological space and let $A \subseteq X$.  A point $x \in X$  is in the boundary of $A$ if every open set containing $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X−A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a false claim. By (one) definition of boundary we have $\text{Bd}(A) = \overline{A}\setminus A^\circ$ where $A^\circ$ is the interior of $A$. Hence $$A \cup (\overline{A}\setminus A^\circ) = \overline{A}$$

We have equality from the union above since $A^\circ \subset A$. Hence $$A\cup \text{Bd}(A) = \text{Cl}(A)$$

---

**Edit:** As requested, here is how you could prove this result with sets, elements and double containment.

Let $x \in \overline{A}$. It should be clear that either $x \in A^\circ$ or $x \notin A^\circ$. In the latter case, this means $x\in \overline{A}/A^\circ$ so clearly $x\in A\cup \overline{A}/A^\circ$. In the former case, we can use the fact that $A^\circ \subset A$ to see that $x \in A$ so $x \in A \cup \overline{A}/A^\circ$. Hence, $\overline{A} \subset A\cup \overline{A}/A^\circ$.

Now let $y \in  A\cup \overline{A}/A^\circ$ and suppose FTSOC that $y \notin \overline{A}$. Since $A,A^\circ \subset \overline{A}$ this means $y \notin A$ and $y\notin A^\circ$, so $x\notin A \cup \overline{A}$. It is obvious that $A\cup \overline{A} /A^\circ \subset A \cup \overline{A}$ so  $y \notin A\cup \overline{A} /A^\circ$, a contradiction. Thus $\overline{A} = A \cup \overline{A}/A^\circ$.

Comment: The boundary is equal to the closure minus the *interior*, not the closure minus the whole set...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi How does it look now?

Comment: I think he has a different definition of boundary, since he states that there can be points in the boundary that are not limit points..

Comment: @MohamedHashi the definition may be different, but it must still be equivalent.

Comment: Why should it be equivalent? This is the usual definition and who knows what kind of definition he has in his head.

Comment: Is he necessarily a 'he'?

Comment: @MohamedHashi they are equivalent because they are both a definition of the same thing? Just as $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ continuity is equivalent to "inverse image of an open set is open" continuity, despite being different definitions

Comment: @Donkey_2009 good point haha. Alyssa isn't a name I've ever heard of a guy having ;)

Comment: Thanks Donkey. I want to loose my reflex to assume someone to be male in male dominated subjects.

Comment: This is my definition of boundary: I do not think this affects anything you have written.  Correct? Let $(X,\mathfrak T)$  be a topological space and let $A \subseteq X$.  A point $x \in X$  is in the boundary of $A$ if every open set containing $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X−A$.

Comment: @AlyssaWallace ultimately that will not affect what I have written. However, if that is the definition you must use you could either prove that your definition is the same as mine, or the proof could be rewritten using only your definition

Comment: We did have to prove your definition of boundary so I will have to find that.  But can you explain a little bit about your statement that we have equality from above since $Int(A) \subseteq A$.  I am still unsure about this.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I would show this with sets and elements?

Comment: @graydad can you talk to me a little about double containment? I am still pondering this proof!

Comment: @AlyssaWallace I added a proof. Let me know if that clears things up!

Comment: Perfect! I feel like I can follow this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting confused with the following: given a topological space $A$, it is not necessarily the case that every point of the closure $\overline{A}$ is the topological limit of some sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ of points of $a$.

Indeed, let $R$ be an uncountable set, and consider the space $X=\{f\colon R\to\{0,1\}\}$.  For a countable set $B\subset A$ and a function $g\colon A\to\{0,1\}$, we define
$$
U_{B,g}=\{f\in X\;\colon\; f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)\textrm{ for all }\alpha\in B\}
$$
The sets $U_{B,g}$ form the basis for a topology on $X$.  Now define a subset $Y$ of $X$ by
$$
Y=\{f\in X\;\colon\;f(\alpha)=0\textrm{ for all but countably many }\alpha\in A\}
$$
Now if $g_1,g_2,g_3,\dots$ is a sequence in $Y$ such that $g_n\to g\in X$, then $g\in Y$.  So $Y$ contains all its limit points.  On the other hand, $Y$ is not closed, since it is dense in $X$.

Comment: I think you meant that set of all limit points of $A$ need not be the closure of $A$. We always have $A\subseteq A^L \subseteq \bar A$, where $A^L$ denotes the set of limit points of convergent sequences in $A$.

Comment: @Ennar Yes I did.